# why nginx load phtml files as html files

Tags: php, nginx, magento2

My site runs perfectly on apache server.Now i am tring to implement on **nginx** server and i have problem like my magento's **phtml** files executes as **html**.I tried and added **"*.phtml"** extension in nginx config file but not succeed.

here my config file

```
cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.com 


server {
listen 80 default_server;

root /usr/share/nginx/mydomain.com/;
index index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm;

server_name domain.com;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.(php|phtml)$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
}
}
```

Please suggest how can i solve "*.html" file to "*.phtml" in nginx?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
location ~ \.(php|phtml)$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
}
```